# Can phonon follow similar curve as photons follow in blackbody radiation?

Tags: photons, thermal-radiation, bosons, phonons

I recently came to know about phonons, and how similar they are to photons, like both are bosons and mu = 0 in both cases, only difference between them as far as I know is there spin states (phonons have 3 spin states, whereas photons 2). So my questions is as we know that photons follow Planck's law (blackbody radiation), so is it possible for phonons to follow a similar curve? And if true, have we measured it yet?

Comment: I don't understand this question. Photon don't follow Planck's law because they're bosons or massless or whatever, but because the specific thermal process of blackbodies that produces photons produces that distribution. A photon that's not produced from blackbody radiation has nothing to do with Planck's law. Where do you think the connection between phonons and blackbody radiation is coming from here?

Comment: @ACuriousMind, I don't think there's anything specific about the thermal process of blackbodies; it really just requires thermal equilibrium, which is a very general concept. That's why the "Cavity with a hole" model works for explaining blackbody radiation. Any cavity full of truly massless (linear dispersion relation) bosons at thermal equilibrium will radiate with a distribution following Plank's law (possibly with different constants). This is just like saying that a balloon with a hole in it will "radiate" gas molecules with a Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution regardless of the type of gas.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you're asking if phonons can "radiate" with a distribution of energies like those for blackbody radiation.

If so, the answer is yes. This is often assumed in models of thermal transport. For example, [here](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0031-8914(38)80162-2)'s a classic paper that does exactly that. Similar models are still used today in phonon transport. E.g., phonon transport in nanostructures can be modeled with two "reservoirs" that are in thermal equilibrium and they "radiate" phonons with a blackbody-like distribution into some sort of nanostructure, and the transport properties of the nanostructure are calculated by measuring the power transmitted. See, for example, section 6.2 of [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.07735.pdf) book chapter.

EDIT: To understand why a reservoir of phonons produces blackbody-like radiation, note that a large phonon reservoir connected to a nanostructure is basically the same setup as the ["cavity with a hole"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_body#Cavity_with_a_hole) model for blackbodies.

Comment: The density of states is different between photons and phonons, though.  So while both can be treated as obeying Bose-Einstein statistics and you can use the same procedures to derive the energy spectrum, there will be quantitative differences in the two spectra due to the difference in density of states.

Comment: Absolutely. That's why I said  "blackbody-**like** radiation". That said, for transport, you often care most about acoustic phonons in the frequency range where the dispersion relation is fairly linear. The result is very similar to blackbody radiation with some different constants. (Again, see Casimir's paper for an example.)

Answer (score 0):

Phonons are vibrations in a material. Usually we look at phonons in the context of a crystal that has a specific arrangement of atoms. This structure is periodic and like electrons going through a crystal you have a band structure.

From the band structure of the phonons you will find that you can have two varieties: acoustic phonons and optical phonons. This doesn’t mean that an optical phonons is like a phonons but that  the higher energy modes of vibration in ionic crystals these loses could be excited by electromagnetic magnetic radiation.

From an atom point of view if you have a phonons propagating you would see neighboring atoms moving relative to each other like a wave, but at specific wavelengths or modes of vibration.

So phonons are nothing like blackbody radiation in  terms of having a spectrum, but instead only occur in certain energy ranges. In fact sometimes it is convenient to think phonons as particles.

There are a lot of experiments where people either intentionally or inadvertently try to manipulate phonons, or photons and phonons interact. So yes, in a sense people can measure phonons as a function of energy and have a spectrum.

Phonons can have other wavelike properties and coherence and some people claim to make phonons lasers where the phonons are amplified in a similar way as photon laser.